# Get animated GIFs into LaTeX presentation

Tags: graphics, animations, gif

I am new to LaTeX. I am trying to put a GIF into my LaTeX presentation. 
I followed [@samcarter guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation) here.

I have 23 pictures so I changed something and tried this:

```
\transduration<0-23>{0}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{something}
```

But I always get this warning:

> LaTeX Warning: File `something-0.png' not found on input line 132
>       /LaTeX_Vorlage_Presentations/.example.tex.
>       swp:132: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'something-0.png'.

The something.pngs are in the same file folder as the LaTeX stuff too.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always include a complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.  It'll help us much to help you.   In your special case: your title and text talks about GIF images, while the code example says `format=png`.  So I am wondering, which is correct.

Comment: @Jan if you follow the guide he linked it seems like he converted the .gif in .png images of the single frames.

Comment: @idkfa: Sorry, I was editing the question and was wondering about the confusion.  I did not following the link while editing.

Comment: Two questions: 1) can you check that the converted images start with `something-0.png` and not, say `something-1.png` ? 2) are you compiling with pdflatex? or latex or something else?

Comment: And another: some operating systems are picky with capitalization. Are your images of type `png` or `PNG`? Can you check with an `ls` in the folder of the images?

Answer (score 18):

Here is the procedure on GNU/Linux.  I took the `gif` image from [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291650/10995).

[image]

First you need to burst the `gif` into single frames.  I use the ImageMagick tool `convert` for this.

```bash
mkdir gif
convert -coalesce animation.gif gif/frame-%d.png
```

This will create the files `frame-0.png` through `frame-36.png` in the subdirectory `gif/`.  To include this in a `beamer` presentation I use the [`animate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate) package.  It offers the command `\animategraphics` to conatenate single images to an animation.  The syntax is

```
\animategraphics[<options>]{<frame rate>}{<path prefix>}{<start frame>}{<end frame>}
```

In our case, the path prefix is `gif/frame-`.  The start frame is 0, the last frame is 36.  A frame rate of 12 is empirically chosen, since it looks best.  The image is too large for the slide, so we scale it down using `width=\textwidth`.  Here is the full example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \animategraphics[width=\textwidth]{12}{gif/frame-}{0}{36}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*N.B.:* This is known to work with Adobe Reader, PDF-XChange, and Foxit.  (Thanks @AlexG)

Comment: PDF-XChange and Foxit should work too.

Comment: The `loop` and `autoplay` options could be added to produce the animated-gif-feel.

Comment: Some gifs are size-optimized (containing differential frames). To have *complete* single frames after bursting, always add `-coalesce` to the `convert` commandline, as in the answers to the [cited question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240243) .

Comment: I tried it this way & it worked - thank you so much! You guys saved my presentation