# Draw a animated gif of cosine, tangent and cotangent function

Tags: animations, gif

Could you help me with drawing animated GIFs of cosine, tangent and cotangent functions? I really don't know how to make them. I would be very happy if they were similar to this GIF. [In this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291627/draw-an-animated-gif-of-trigonometry-function)  Henri Menke did an animated GIF of the sine function. 
[image: sine function]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The answer you've linked should already provide you with everything you need. Could you please provide more information what you've tried so far and what you have achieved, and where your specific problems arise? Did you manage to compile the latex document?

Comment: Well, isn't Henri's code a good starting point, at least for the cosine function? Read and try to understand it. Do-it-for-me questions are not really appreciated here.

Comment: Thanks jjbd, but unfortunately I don't manage to compile the latex document. Basically, I would concentrate only on these three gifs, not latex documents. Please, I you find this so easy, could you help me?

Comment: Ok, I will try with cosine.

Comment: If you don't want to bother with installing TeX yourself, you could try an online LaTeX editor/compiler, such as [**ShareLaTeX**](http://www.sharelatex.com).

Comment: Sorry but could you tell me how should I start? I suppose that acapit "fill circle and plot" in Menke's code should not be changed because they're relating to the unit circle, yes?