# Why does this test with ifthenelse not compile?

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

Why does the following test using `\ifthenelse` not compile:

```
\documentclass[border=30pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate, calc}%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
 \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,4}{

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0)
      to[V,v=$U_q$] (0,2) % The voltage source
      to[short] (2,2)
      to[R=$R_1$] (2,0) % The resistor
      to[short] (0,0);
      \draw (2,2)
      to[short] (4,2)
      to[R=$R_2$] (4,0)
      to[short] (2,0); 
        \ifthenelse{\x<2}{\fill[color=red] (0,\x) circle (3pt);}{}
 \end{circuitikz}
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

On compilation I get the following error:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read
again>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `\ifnum` (which is what `\ifthenelse` calls) only takes whole numbers (no fractions). Therefore you need another test. A very simple attempt:

```
\documentclass[border=30pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{animate, calc}%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \xifnum } { }
    {
        \fp_compare:nTF
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,4}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{circuitikz}
     \draw (0,0)
      to[V,v=$U_q$] (0,2) % The voltage source
      to[short] (2,2)
      to[R=$R_1$] (2,0) % The resistor
      to[short] (0,0);
      \draw (2,2)
      to[short] (4,2)
      to[R=$R_2$] (4,0)
      to[short] (2,0); 
      \xifnum{\x<2}{\fill[color=red] (0,\x) circle (3pt);}{}
 \end{circuitikz}
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or using `\foreach \x in {1,2,...,40}` and comparing `\x` with `20`, with `(0,\x/10)` as coordinate.

Comment: @egreg That sounds far too simple (and has no expl3) ;)

Comment: thank you for all, i used this reply to improve   my question [about circuitikz ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426459/how-to-make-animation-to-show-how-the-electric-current-flow-works/426504#426504)