# How do I have to implement the following comparison [TikZ]

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

How do I have to implement the following comparison?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathparse{sin(60)}
 \let\x=\pgfmathresult
 \ifnumgreater{\x}{0}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to know whether a number is greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, but \x seems to be not merely a number. TeX's complaint is `Missing = inserted for \ifnum`

Comment: `\ifnum` only works on whole numbers.

Comment: Maybe kind of related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426483/why-ifthenelse-doesnt-compile-for-me/426485

Comment: Yes, exactlyyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifnum` which is called does only work with whole numbers (no fractions). Therefore you need another test:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \xifnum } { }
    {
        \fp_compare:nTF
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \xifnum{sin(60) > 0}{
    \node {x};
 }{
    \node {y};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```