# Error while trying to compute modulo 3 inside a foreach loop in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

My goal is to draw an array of shapes in the following fashion: square, square, triangle, square, square, triangle ...

I use a `\foreach` loop in which I use modular arithmetic to determine when to draw a triangle. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.35,
triangle/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, scale=2.5},
square/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, scale=2}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
{
    \ifthenelse{mod(\i,3) = 0}
    {
        \node[triangle] (\i) at (\i,0) {};
    }
    {
        \node[square] (\i) at (\i,0) {};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
```

The most related question about these error is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426483/why-does-this-test-with-ifthenelse-not-compile) but it considers decimal numbers, which is not my case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the log file you'll see the entire error, where you can see it complains about `m`, so I take it `m` is what is not a number. Here `m` is the `m` in `mod`.

Point being, `\ifthenelse` doesn't know about `pgf`s math functions, and `mod` isn't parsed in that location. You can do the calculation with `\foreach [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i,3));}]` and do the comparison against `\j`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.35,
triangle/.style = {draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, scale=2.5},
square/.style = {draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, scale=2}]
\foreach [evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i,3));}] \i in {1,...,9}
{
    \ifthenelse{\j = 0}
    {
        \node[triangle] (\i) at (\i,0) {};
    }
    {
        \node[square] (\i) at (\i,0) {};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This answer is more than I expected!