# Producing animated figure using tikz

Tags: beamer, animations, gif

This is my first attempt to produce animated figures using TikZ and since I'm going to teach circuits, I want to start by reproducing the circuit in a previous post ["How to make animation to show how the electric current flow works?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426459/how-to-make-animation-to-show-how-the-electric-current-flow-works) (please note that I'm talking about the last animated circuit in the post).

Now, I tried to run the provided code, and I got the below PDF file:

[image]

And then I read that I need to use the TeX files provided in GIF image in `beamer` presentation and the author said that if my OS is not Windows, then I have to adapt the Windows shell command to my macOS shell command.

Can anyone please advise me on how to do that to get the final results with any harm?

Comment: Do the answers to this question solve your problem? [Converting beamer slides to animated images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389634/138900)