# Creating some gif with tikz: Any idea to get better result?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have used this tikz  to generate some  GIF. Here are the code and the result. Any idea to make it better

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt}]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1);
 \node at ({cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)}) {\textcolor{blue}{$\bullet$}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
   }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: add `\useasboundingbox (-1.5,-1.5)rectangle(1.5,1.5);`

Comment: @AndréC Looks like an answer to me

Comment: @JosephWright I don't understand, what are you talking about?

Comment: @AndréC Joseph's comment means that your comment looks suitable to become a proper answer to this question. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Indeed, but one answer has already been accepted and my last answer to an accepted question had no vote, yet my solution is completely original and innovative.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492532/194579.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** You could put a larger bounding box around the whole diagram (I think @AndréC's option from the comments is conceptually better than the path I originally had even if the effect is the same), make the loop only go to 350° so you don't get the pause at the end, and change from a bullet in a node to directly drawing a circle. @BlackMild's suggestion to use `(\angle:1)` instead of the trig functions is also good.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \angle in {0,10,...,350}
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \fill[blue] (\angle:1) circle (0.07);
    \useasboundingbox (-1.1,-1.1) rectangle (1.1,1.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

The animated GIF was created using ImageMagick. It's animation documentation can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/).

I use a simple shell script for the conversation:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

BASE=`basename $1 .pdf`
PDF="$BASE.pdf"
GIF="$BASE.gif"
RESOLUTION=300

CONVERT=/usr/bin/convert
CONVERTOPTS="-density $RESOLUTION -delay 8 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove"

echo "Converting to TSX GIF..."
$CONVERT $CONVERTOPTS $PDF $GIF > /dev/null
```

Comment: How the series of `pdf` images is converted to `gif` animation?

Comment: @zarko `convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif` for 100/4=25 FPS

Comment: @Zarko, I added to my answer.

Comment: @DavidPurton, thank you. so far I never use `ImageMagic`

Comment: @AlexG, where to use your code? In command prompt  (WinEdt)?

Comment: @DavidPurton I see your gif seems "lurched" ...

Comment: @zarko yes, commandline. See: ImageMagick.org

Comment: @user173875, I didn't take into account the large default padding on the node, so the rectangular path making the bounding box was a bit small. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPurton A better use: `\node at (\angle:1) {\textcolor{blue}{$\bullet$}};
`

Comment: @BlackMild, Perhaps it would be better to get rid of the node and text all together and just draw a blue circle. I mainly took the question as how can I improve the animation.

Comment: @DavidPurton yes! it should be this `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,10,...,350}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) circle(1.4);
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\fill[blue] (\i:1) circle(.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild, that's basically what I put in my most recent update. Thanks for your suggestions!