# Save animation from LATEX as a gif

Tags: animations, gif

I have an animated PDF as I created an animated figure using:

```
\begin{animateinline}[controls, autoplay]{12}
\multiframe{65}{i=1+1}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}

#
# Something here
#
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
   
}
\end{animateinline}
```

I need to include this animation in a PowerPoint presentation (there are some reasons for not using beamer). Is there any way to save the animation as a gif?

I am sorry I know this may be more of a PowerPoint question but animated PDFs are not that common outside of the TeX universum.

Comment: Not being a TikZ user, I cannot answer that, but... Any possibility you could run a screen recorder program, play the PDF, record the animation to a file format that PowerPoint understands?

Comment: Two solutions are given in [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291627/draw-an-animated-gif-of-trigonometry-function).

Comment: Another [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44682/295527).

Comment: Yes, there is. Use the `standalone` document class and `export` as class option. This outputs a multipage PDF with the animation frames. Then convert this to animated gif with ImageMagick (or something else). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136666/exporting-animation-created-with-animate-package