# Triangle with 3 endpoints

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to look for a 3d triangle with 3 points labeled like this : [image] but I just need 3 points like; (1,0,2), (0,-1,1) and (2,1,2). How to do this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46682/making-a-3d-colored-pyramid-in-tikz

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213859/197451

Comment: http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/sketch.pdf

Comment: @Sandra-- does this answer help?

Comment: @Sandra Few suggestions: Consider using `\arccos` instead of `arccos` and `\iff` instead of `\Leftrightarrow` (looks better, and tells more - "what you see is what you mean" paradigm).

Answer (score 2):

The code below is in noway a complete answer but intends to give a start point in plotting 3D coordinates in LaTeX/Tikz-3dplot

The vertex shown as A2 was originally shown as

```
\coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,0,5)$}] (A) at (0,0,5);
```

I have simplly changed it to A2 to suit your requirement

Similarly for the vertices marked as A1 and C2--Check out if all clear or more help required

[image]

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{A2}] (A2) at (0,0,5);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{C2}] (C2) at (2,0,2);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,3,3)$}] (C) at (0,3,3);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{A1}] (A1) at (5,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,5,0)$}] (E) at (0,5,0);

    \draw[->] (O) -- (6,0,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,6,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,6);

    \filldraw[draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.1] (A2) -- (C2) -- (2,3,0) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.1] (C2) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.1] (C) -- (0,3,0) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \fill[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (C2) -- (A2) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \fill[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (C) -- (E) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \draw[blue] (C2) -- (A1) -- (E) -- (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Courtesy--https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=5qq

### EDIT

In line with the suggestion @Sebastiano

> color fill

has been done and @Sigur

> standalone

deployed

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,0,5)$}] (A) at (0,0,5);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{$(2,0,2)$}] (B) at (2,0,2);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,3,3)$}] (C) at (0,3,3);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{$(5,0,0)$}] (D) at (5,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,5,0)$}] (E) at (0,5,0);

    \draw[->] (O) -- (6,0,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,6,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,6);

    \filldraw[draw=brown,fill=brown,fill opacity=0.3] (A) -- (B) -- (2,3,0) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (B) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] (C) -- (0,3,0) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3] (B) -- (D) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.3] (C) -- (E) -- (2,3,0)-- cycle;

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Added a bit more symmetry to the triangle--A'--B'--C'--D'--E' are the respective mid points of the triangle sides

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{calc}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,0,5)$}] (A) at (0,0,5);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{$(5,0,0)$}] (D) at (5,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,5,0)$}] (E) at (0,5,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$(0,0,0)$}] (O) at (0,0,0);


    \draw[->] (O) -- (6,0,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,6,0);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,6);

    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red, fill opacity=0.1] (A)--(D)--(E)--cycle;
    \coordinate[label=above right:$A’$] (Aprime) at ($(A)!0.5!(E)$);
    \coordinate[label=above left:$B’$] (Bprime) at ($(A)!0.5!(D)$);
    \coordinate[label=below right:$C’$] (Cprime) at ($(D)!0.5!(E)$);
    \coordinate[label=above left:$D’$] (Dprime) at ($(O)!0.5!(D)$);
    \coordinate[label=above right:$E’$] (Eprime) at ($(O)!0.5!(E)$);


    \filldraw[draw=red, fill=red,fill opacity=.5] (Bprime)--(Dprime)--(Cprime)--cycle;
    \filldraw[draw=blue, fill=blue,fill opacity=.5] (Aprime)--(Eprime)--(Cprime)--cycle;

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should change the colors and give the correct fill. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano--done color fill

Comment: I'd use `standalone` class to produce the figure.

Comment: @Sigur---done `standalone`